# Display Counter or any other thing till the time any command is running in script in Powershell

Tags: powershell, timer, counter

I have a script which has some commands that takes time to complete like 30 sec to 1 minute to get completed.
What I am trying to achieve is that till the time command is doing it works in the background we should get some counter or timer or anything getting displayed till the command is running.
When command gets completed, the counter gets stopped.

The user running the script should be aware that yes something is running.
For example like when we open any site and it takes time to load, we get the sand timer or something else as in the display.

Comment: Depending on the commend you could use [Write-Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Any luck anyone ?

Comment: Did you take a look at `Write-Progress`? What have you tried so far? Can you share some code to play with?

Comment: I am not sure how to implement Write-Progress for some command.

Comment: So you might start digging into it. ;-)  Without any further info we will not be able to help you. You did not show anything yet.

Comment: Thanks Olaf. Let's take a simple sleep command. i.e sleep 10, so till the time it is running i want to timer to run and when it gets completed times also goes completed.

Comment: That's impossible. You wrote there are commands running in the background. Powershell is single threaded by default. You would need to use any kind of background job.

Comment: If I got you right, I should make my command to run in the background and then monitor its progress

Comment: Exactly. That's what I meant. ;-)

Comment: can u help me running below command in the background.                                                                     $Incident=& $ticket | Out-GridView  -title "Select one or more ticket to update" -PassThru'

Comment: Please start with learning the very basics of Powershell first. You will learn as well how to get help.  [Get-Help about-Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs?view=powershell-7)